# Folder in resources directory!

Tags: objective-c, arrays, resources, directory

I have a folder named "test" in my resources. I have a lot of images in there. How can I load all the images in the folder "test" in an array?

I tried with:

```
testArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"gif" inDirectory:@"Test"]];
```

But it doesn't work!

Thx for your help!

greez franhu

Answer (score 0):

pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory: gets you the filenames.  Assuming you want the actual images, you might do:

```
NSArray *fileNames = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"gif" inDirectory:@"Test"];
for(NSString *fileName in fileNames)
{
    // load the file here and put it in another array
}
```

Other things to check:

Open up your application bundle and verify that the Test directory exists in it.

If you're doing this on iOS, consider using [UIImage imageNamed:] instead, which will search your bundle for the image in question automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i only load the filenames in the fileNames array and then make a alertView with [fileNames count]. [fileNames count] = 0. that isn't correct if i have 10 images in my test folder?

Comment: Yeah, you should get 10 file names. Try passing nil for the directory name. It may be that your resources aren't in a subdirectory in your bundle.